# android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE: not triggered on Wifi disconnect

Tags: android, wifi, wifimanager

Is it normal to only have a broadcast intent with action `NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` (whose constant value is  `android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE`) when a Wifi connection is coming back up?   I.e. I don't get this intent when Wifi is being disconnected.

**UPDATE:** I am mostly interested to >= 2.2 Froyo

Comment: I had the same problems for weeks and I think it's normal (or a bug ;)). I know this doesn't help, but just for information...

Comment: Just to clarify for future readers: that intent is for the state (disabled, enabling, enabled, disabling) of the wifi transceiver, basically telling you if wifi is on or off. You were looking for the state of connectivity, which is different.

Comment: @JeffE: nope - __"android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"__ corresponds to `NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` which is for net connectivity. `WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION` is for enable, disable etc - corresponds to __"android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED"__ Please delete your confusing comment. To the OP - I think the answer by  M Granja is the correct one

Answer (score 24, accepted):

> public static final String
> SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION
>
> Since: API Level 1
>
> Broadcast intent
> action indicating that a connection to
> the supplicant has been established
> (and it is now possible to perform
> Wi-Fi operations) or the connection to
> the supplicant has been lost. One
> extra provides the connection state as
> a boolean, where true means CONNECTED.
>
> **See Also**
>
> EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_CONNECTED
>
> Constant Value: "android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE"

In android's API it says that it's not a good idea to check STATE_CHANGE for network connectivity and instead you should use SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION. this will notice an establishment to a wifi network, and the **disconnection** of a wifi network. I don't know if this might help you, but I do hope so. [LINK](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html#SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION)

Comment: I get a connection change event on "disconnect" now! Thanks!

Comment: I don't know but SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION didn't work for me. It was never getting fired. I had to use  WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION to do the same thing. And it worked like a charm!!

Answer (score 21):

I had a similar need in my project and ended up having to use both.

The android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE action sends a broadcast when the network is connected, but usually before the device has an IP address, so I needed the android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE action for that.

The android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE action receives a broadcast on disconnect only if the device is disconnecting from a network, but wifi is still enabled (when hotspot goes out of range, for example)

So you should put both actions for the receiver in the manifest:

```
<receiver android:name="net.moronigranja.tproxy.WifiReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE"/>
                    <action android:name="android.net.wifi.supplicant.CONNECTION_CHANGE" />
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and you put an if to check which action is being called in the intent. Here is the onReceive method of the BroadcastReceiver in my code:

```
public void onReceive(Context c, Intent intent) {
      if(intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION)){ 
          boolean connected = intent.getBooleanExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_SUPPLICANT_CONNECTED, false);
          if(!connected) {
               //Start service for disconnected state here
          }
      }

      else if(intent.getAction().equals(WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION)){
          NetworkInfo netInfo = intent.getParcelableExtra(WifiManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);
          if( netInfo.isConnected() )
          {
              //Start service for connected state here.
          }   
      }
  }
```

Comment: even though i used a separate class for my broadcast receiver, checking the supplicant was the key to solving my problem.

Comment: I don't know but SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION didn't work for me. It was never getting fired. I had to use WifiManager.NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION to do the same thing. And it worked like a charm!!

Comment: Yes, NETWORK_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION worked like charm, no need to add on the manifest.

Comment: @unrealsoul007 really really late answer, but in current state of affairs (Lollipop+), I noticed I stopped getting SUPPLICANT_CONNECTION_CHANGE_ACTION broadcasts whenever the connect/authenticate/acquire IP/disconnect flow was triggered by the system and not my app. So I'm guessing there is some process isolation preventing retrieval of BCs, either on the Android system or even low level Linux layers. Pretty much I'm assessing user apps can't ubiquitously establish a difference between connected, with-ip, without-ip, auth failed among other types of state of the supplicant

Comment: I noticed that too. You still get the broadcast if mobile data is disabled, though, when wireless disconnects.