# How to create a broadcast receiver of the WiFi to dispay its state accordingly

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-wifi, connectivity

Below I am displaying the current state of the ´WiFi´ network using a `textview`, but if the current state of the network changes, for example while the App is running and the user turned the `WiFi` off, the `textview` would change accordingly. what i am trying to do is, to have a `textview` that can display the current status of the `WiFi` network accordingy.

How to achieve this. I hope  my question is clear.

**Code**:

```
private boolean IsWiFiConnected() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ConnectivityManager mconnMgr = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo mNWInfo = mconnMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

    if (mNWInfo != null) {
        if (mNWInfo.isConnected()) {
            setText(R.id.tv_conn_status, "WiFi is now connected: "+mNWInfo.isConnected());
            return true;
        }else if (mNWInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
            setText(R.id.tv_conn_status, "WiFi is now connecting/connected: "+mNWInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting());
            return true;
        }else if (mNWInfo.isAvailable()) {
            setText(R.id.tv_conn_status, "WiFi is now available: "+mNWInfo.isAvailable());
            return false;
        }else if (mNWInfo.isFailover()) {
            setText(R.id.tv_conn_status, "WiFi is now in faiover: "+mNWInfo.isFailover());
            return false;
        }else if (mNWInfo.isRoaming()) {
            setText(R.id.tv_conn_status, "WiFi is now available: "+mNWInfo.isRoaming());
            return false;
        }   
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When your app is running, you can register a `BroadcastReceiver` that will be triggered on changes to the WIFI connectivity. When this happens you can update your view.

See http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html and
[android.net.wifi.STATE_CHANGE: not triggered on Wifi disconnect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365395/android-net-wifi-state-change-not-triggered-on-wifi-disconnect)